# Nightmare with Pug and Express Rendering

Tags: mongodb, express, pug

I am quiet new to express and Pug. I'm making a very basic application to help with my learning. I successfully have the following GET route which exposes the MongoDB elements in a JSON format:

```
    //get a list of projects from the database
router.get('/projects', function(req,res){
    project.find({},function(err,docs){
        if(err)res.json(err);
        else res.render('project', {projects: docs});
    });
});
```

projects.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  .main.container
    .row
     .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
        h1.display-4.m-b-2 All Current Projects
        ul
          each project in projects
           li #{title} #{description}
```

I'm wanting to have this information displayed on a client side - rendering on a pug file. I have tried numerous way to do this, but I am continuing to get errors. How do I go about successfully displaying this information?

Comment: Could you share your pug file ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your pug code, it's not clear in the comment

Comment: Apologies, updated with the pug file.

Comment: Note that the view name is `projects.pug`  with an 's' you have to do `res.render('projects', {projects: docs});`

Answer (score 1):

`each` its like a casual `for-each` loop. You started loop but didt use any items. If you named item as `project`, you need to call your property, for instace `project.title`

```
extends layout

block content
  .main.container
    .row
     .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
        h1.display-4.m-b-2 All Current Projects
        ul
          each project in projects
           li #{project.title} #{project.description}
```